# Forward a JSONencoded string to another page

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble taking a string (called $name) from one page and outputing that string to another page.

This is a snippet of my code from where I think it is relevant:

```
    if ($_POST['to'])
    {
        // Get all relevant messages
        $get_msgs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE touser='$from'");
        $mailbox = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_msgs))
        {
        $mailbox[] = $row;
        }

        // Make a string with the JSON array in it
        $name = "{ \"mailbox\":".json_encode($mailbox)." }";

        // now here, how do I simply forward this string to a page called page2.php

    }
```

A. What should the code be for page2.php? (even though all I want it to do is really just echo $name)

B. If I run the above code multiple times, would page2.php be cleared, and refreshed each time with the new $name?

Thank you in advance for the help guys.

I tried this:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myValue']=$name;
```

And in page2 used:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
```

But no data was forwarded to page 2

Comment: Why not use sessions?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how to use them exactly

Comment: @Jon - I edited the question with what I tried.

Comment: Did you check on page one that `$name` contained the data?  `session_start()` also needs to be at the top of the page. ^^

Comment: Actually I did not check if $name had data. I'm going to add an echo $name then. And I also didn't have session_start at the top. I'll move it there and try it out now thanks.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure why but putting in an echo $name there leaves the page blank.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 way :

some one set session to passing array to new page :

```
sesstion_strat() ;
$_SESSION['name'] = $name ;

-> in page2 

sesstion_strat() ;
$name = $_SESSION['name'] ;
```

2en way :
pass array with get method , this method not good for long arrays and spcial chars.

```
header("Location: page2.php?name=".$name);

-> in page2 
$name = $_GET['name'] ;
```

or use curl for post data :

you see sample here :

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I tried your code as well, but it was a blank page...I'm now thinking that maybe $name has nothing in it. I'm going to test it out and see.

Comment: Is there a reason you added the ( -> in page2 )? Is it supposed to be part of the code? Or are you telling me in other words "and then in page2, write the code ..."

Comment: Yeah I tried it like that, thanks. But I realized that somehow my code doesn't work..from that day of my comment to now.